# Вопрос по sleep()

Tags: php, sleep

test.php:

```
file_put_contents(rand().'.txt', 'test');
sleep(10000);
```

Открываю я site.ru/test.php и файлы должны создаваться в течении 10 секунд. Но создаётся только 1, хотя по идее, должно быть несколько. Ведь за 10 секунд не создаётся же 1 файл, их должно быть больше.

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: цикл сделали бы - цены вам не было бы. и все работало бы. много бы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно работает! У тебя генерируется случайное число, затем создаётся файл с именем "случайное число . txt", и записывается в него строка "test". После сценарий тормозит на 10000 секунд и завершается работа.

Попробуй так :

```
<?php

$tstart             =   time();

$howlongmywork      =   $tstart - time();

while ($howlongmywork <= 10) {

    file_put_contents(rand().'.txt', 'test');

    $howlongmywork  =   $tstart - time();
}

?>
```

Comment: @Андрей Аршинов, 1 раз в минуту как прикрепить сюда? :)

Comment: Сколько раз нужно это проделать? Нужно условие выхода из цикла.

Comment: @Андрей Аршинов, это нужно делать бесконечно. Даже если юзер закрыл вкладку сайта. ignore_user_abort(1); вроде..

Comment: Я ответил на вопрос, дальше уже пробуй сам.

Answer (score -1):

`sleep` - секундый таймер.

`usleep` - микросекундый.

Comment: а к чему это? :D usleep(20000000); и такая же беда. Файл создаётся только 1 раз за много секунд.

Comment: А вы что хотите? Данная функция останавливает работу скрипта на n секунд/микросекунд.

Comment: @lampa, а как сделать, чтобы в течении 30 секунд, создавался файл? Именно на PHP. Ну то есть открыл вкладку и оно начинает. Нужно именно посредством php функций, а не ajax.

Comment: Так чем вам цикл не подойдет? while(true)

Comment: @lampa, о! Идея же. А вот теперь немного сложнее. Как сделать 1 раз в две минуты?

Comment: ModaL [Cron][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: @lampa, сейчас объясню что я делаю. А Вы скажите, как реализовали бы именно Вы. Делаю обычную накрутку подписчиков в ВК например. Юзер вводит ссылку и тут же начинается накрутка. А если юзеров 50 например заюзали сервис, то 50 задач в кроне? Уверен, что другие делают как-то по-другому, но как...

Comment: Я не понимаю, вам нужно сделать так, чтобы скрипт делал определенный цикл раз в 2 минуты? Или вам нужно, чтобы через каждые 2 минуты делался запрос?

Comment: Так, как комментарии не оставить, то пишу здесь. @lampa, Вы правильно сказали. > чтобы через каждые 2 минуты делался запрос. Но не на cron и не на ajax и т.д. А открытой вкладкой, именно функциями PHP.